# Has gnome-keyring-daemon replaced ssh-agent in non-headless situations?

Tags: ssh, gnome

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.
In the past, I would add keys to ssh-agent to bypass having to enter my passphrase with ssh.

Recently after a power outage, my PC rebooted and it seems that the environment variable $SSH_AUTH_SOCK is now being handled by gnome-keyring-daemon. When I ssh for the first time, it would prompt me for the passphrase via a gnome dialog box.

Does this mean that whenever I am running on the desktop; I don't need ssh-agent anymore ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer: Yes. However the `gnome-keyring-daemon` supports more than just OpenSSH keys.